# how to link correctly this external js with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to learn myself html and found this js fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/xfkeM/

Now am trying to create a simple webpage ,but seems that am missing something as I can not see the desired output.

Here is my HTML Code part

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='NewFolder/js.custom.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="togglevisibility">Toggle Me 1
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="togglevisibility">Toggle Me 2
        <ul> 
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="togglevisibility">Toggle Me 3
        <ul> 
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<body>
</html>
```

and the custom.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("li>ul").hide();

    $(".togglevisibility")
      .mouseenter(function() {
          $(this).children("ul").slideDown();
      })
      .mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).children("ul").slideUp();
      });
  });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript that executes after page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

Comment: need to include the file jquery.js  include this   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing jQuery itself! include

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Sham — You must add it *before* the script that depends on jQuery.

Comment: @ Quentin this is how the html looks right now <head> <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>; <script type='text/javascript' src='NewFolder/js.custom.js'></script> </head> is that ok  ?

Comment: @Sham: This is okey! Also confirm that you are giving right path for your custom.js i.e. your NewFolder and html file both are at same level.

Comment: @ Mahesh yes the path is rightly mentioned in html but i dint get that "same level" thing at present inside the main directory index.html is present and another directory named js is there and inside that custom.js I think thats ok

Comment: I may be asking too much but can u run my script at your end with the external js

Comment: @Sham: Is your index.html inside the NewFolder ?

Comment: Can you try using  <script type='text/javascript' src='NewFolder/js/custom.js'></script>

Comment: sry for misleading you 
Its working now there was a space in between the directory name

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

include the  file

Comment: @Sham — You must add it *before* the script that depends on jQuery.

Comment: @ Quentin this is how the html looks right now 


<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='NewFolder/js.custom.js'></script>
</head>

is that ok ?